# Odd Zenity-behaviour

Tags: fonts, opensuse, zenity

I have a Bash-script containing Zenity dialog boxes that works fine on Ubuntu 20.04.

However when I start it in openSUSE Leap 42, it looks like this:

[image]

It seems as if some package is missing. Any ideas?

/Paul

Answer (score 0):

A little bit embarrassing. I did not mentioned that the openSUSE Leap 42 was installed on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

There is a dependency between the fonts used in the desktop environment and Zenity. Since no desktop environment was installed, I pulled down Gnome and - voilà - it's working :-)

/Paul